# How to delete item from dictionary and change key of others F#

Tags: dictionary, f#

I'm looking to create a function that takes in a value, finds the value in the dictionary, and then deletes it, while also going through the dictionary and making the key of the values afterwards one less, like so (the keys of values in the dictionary are int values from 1 and up):

```
let deleteitem (item: Gitem) = 
    let mutable count = 1
    while count<=invendict.Count do
        let testitem = invendict.Item[count]
        if item = testitem then
            invendict.Remove[count]
        //from here, look at every value, whos key is higher than the key of 
        the removed value, and decreases the key by one, till every value is looked at
```

Comment: 1) What data structure are using as your dictionary? 2) If your keys are just indices, then using `ResizeArray` will make a lot more sense.

Comment: The dictionary is (Int,Gitem)

Comment: `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, Gitem>`? What do the keys represent so that you need to decrement them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the code snippet in your example, it looks like your keys in the dictionary are just indices into the dictionary (because the loop in your code sample iterates from `1` to `invendict.Count`). In this case, using a dictionary is a bad idea. You can just use `ResizeArray` (which is an F# type alias for .NET generic mutable `List<T>` type).

Removing item from `ResizeArray` has exactly the behaviour you need:

```
let r = ResizeArray ["A";"B";"C"]
r.RemoveAt(1) // Remove the B element
r.[0]         // Returns A as before removal
r.[1]         // Returns C which was at 2 before the removal
```

If you really want to use dictionary, then you will basically need to create a new dictionary - it will likely be more efficient to recreate the dictionary than to remove and add half of its elements.